# SFINAE to determine if a function compiles?

Tags: c++, detection, sfinae

In particular, we build with `-Wunused -Werror`, so if we write

```
auto tmp = calcSomethingToCheckPart1();
auto foo = calcSomethingToCheckPart2(tmp);
MY_ASSERT(bar);
```

it can fail in release with an unused `foo`. `MY_ASSERT` is enabled based on several other macros, and while I could copy/paste those to produce an `ASSERTS_ARE_ENABLED` macro and do

```
if constexpr (ASSERTS_ARE_ENABLED) {
    auto tmp = calcSomethingToCheckPart1();
    auto foo = calcSomethingToCheckPart2(tmp);
    MY_ASSERT(foo);
}
```

but I was curious if I could do it more directly.

I know

```
void fn() {
    bool x = true;
    MY_ASSERT(x);
}
```

will fail to compile if asserts are disabled. It feels like I should be able to use SFINAE tricks to figure that out statically... something like

```
template <typename T> // A template so it doesn't fail immediately...
struct TestForAssert {
    static void test() {
        bool x = true;
        MY_ASSERT(x);
    }
};
```

then use SFINAE to determine if `TestForAssert::test` is enabled, but that doesn't seem to work?: https://godbolt.org/z/PqEPnj

Is this sort of detection possible? If so, how?

PS
I know I could probably do

```
MY_ASSERT([&]() {
    auto tmp = calcSomethingToCheckPart1();
    auto foo = calcSomethingToCheckPart2(tmp);
    return foo; 
});
```

but I'm curious to understand the limitations of SFINAE.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm 99.99% sure that the answer will be that this is not possible. SFINAE only detects whether the invocations are well-formed. It doesn't check whether something will compile -- and even if it could, it wouldn't be able to check if a compiler's _optional warnings_ affect this.

Comment: I don't get how your first code can fail for an unused `foo`, when you use `foo` in the second line.

Comment: You can use `(void)bar;` to explicitly silence warnings about `bar` not being used with no side effect.

Comment: Or `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Comment: In Release mode, `MY_ASSERT(cond)` could be defined like `(void)typeid(cond)`

Comment: @prapin Using `typeid` is an interesting solution to prevent any side-effects from occurring, but requires including `<typeinfo>`. I think the same effect could be achievable without the include-requirement by simply using `sizeof`: `(void) sizeof(cond)`

Comment: @NathanOliver my mistake. I rephrased it so `foo` is the one it would complain about. @françois-andrieux, @raymond-chen, the issue here is that in release mode, I don't want to calculate the thing I'm asserting hence not `(void)` or `[[maybe_unused]]`. @prapin good point. Ultimately for me this question is really about the SFINAE aspect.

Comment: @Human-Compiler, I don't follow.

Comment: @Human-Compiler to your first answer: I suspect you are correct. However, I don't quite grok the difference between SFINAE figuring out if, e.g., `T::foo()` exists versus if `T::foo()` compiles. Is it that SFINE doesn't have to actually instantiate the function, it just checks if the function is declared?

The more I think about it, it does feel like having the compiler produce different output depending on warning level really ought to be impossible.

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused  the example is exactly what you need

Comment: @Ben That's correct -- SFINAE doesn't instantiate the function. SFINAE just checks that the the expression is well-formed. Even if the function had a failing `static_assert`, SFINAE can't detect this. If the compiler _could_ somehow detect compiler-errors (especially triggered by warnings), then I think it'd lead to potentially scary situations. Imagine how confusing it would be if a function overload resolved differently based entirely on the warning flags you enabled

Comment: @PiotrNycz it's not. I want to avoid evaluating lines based on if the variable is used. If the optimizer were clever enough, it would, I guess, but in general it can't know if we are calling pure functions.

Comment: You can use `(void)((decltype(cond)*)nullptr)` if you don't want to use `typeid`.

Comment: @Human-Compiler that makes sense. I had always pictured SFINAE as "ignore e.g., member functions that can't work for that type"... but it's not quite like that... Is there a way to ask `S<int>` if it can do `.front()` in https://godbolt.org/z/fxWsY5 ?